# Draw grids on the xy-, xz, and yz-planes

Tags: graphics

I would like to draw grids on the coordinate planes.  I see that Mathematica has a built in function called facegrid but it seems to want a primitive as input.  Even if I give it a blank input it used the faces of the plan input to determine which faces are which.  This seems to make it impossible to draw something like I have below.  How would I graph something like this below?  Don't need the colors, just the lines of a grid.

[image]

Comment: You don´t need to plot anything: As an example `Graphics3D[{}, FaceGrids -> All, 
 FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed]]` works just fine...

Comment: Oh man...I feel dumb.  Thank you.  I think I'll delete this post.

Comment: @YvesKlett -  I updated the question... I realized I wasn't asking the question correctly.   I don't believe you can use facegrid to create grids on coordinate planes that overlap like they do in the pic.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 planes = {
   {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}},
   {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}},
   {{0, 1/2, 1/2}, {0, 1, 0}}};

Graphics3D[InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, #] & /@ planes, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Just for a different flavour, you can also use `Mesh` on a plane.

```
ContourPlot3D[{x == 0, y == 0, z == 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,1}, {z, -1, 1},
 ContourStyle -> Lighter@{Blue, Green, Red}, Mesh -> 5, MeshStyle -> Black,
 Ticks -> False, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, LabelStyle -> 14]
```

[image]

The `Mesh->5` defines how many lines you want.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a way to do this with graphics primitives:

```
grid[{v1_, v2_}, size_, color_] := {
  Lighting -> "Neutral", FaceForm[Lighter@color], EdgeForm[color], Opacity[.9],
  Polygon[{
      (v1 #[[1]] + v2 #[[2]]) + .5 (-v1 - v2),
      (v1 #[[1]] + v2 #[[2]]) + .5 (v1 - v2),
      (v1 #[[1]] + v2 #[[2]]) + .5 (v1 + v2),
      (v1 #[[1]] + v2 #[[2]]) + .5 (-v1 + v2)
      }] & /@
   Tuples[Range[-size, size, 1], {2}]
  }
Graphics3D[{
  grid[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 10, Black],
  grid[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 10, Darker@Green],
  grid[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 10, Red],
  },
 ImageSize -> 1000
 ]
```

which produces

[image]

Just for fun, here is a way to reproduce your image, using textures:

```
chessTexture[color1_, color2_] := With[{size = 1},
  Graphics[
   {
    EdgeForm[None],
    color1,
    Rectangle[{0, 0}, {size/2, size/2}],
    Rectangle[{size/2, size/2}, {size, size}],
    color2,
    Rectangle[{size/2, 0}, {size, size/2}],
    Rectangle[{0, size/2}, {size/2, size}]
    },
   ImagePadding -> 0,
   PlotRangePadding -> None
   ]
  ]
chessboard[{v1_, v2_}, size_, color1_, color2_] := 
 With[{p = {0, 0, 0}},
  {
   EdgeForm[None], Lighting -> "Neutral",
   Texture[chessTexture[color1, color2]],
   Polygon[
    {p - size (v1 + v2), p + size v1 - size v2, p + size (v1 + v2), 
     p - size v1 + size v2},
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {size, 0}, {size, size}, {0, 
       size}}
    ]
   }
  ]
Graphics3D[{
  chessboard[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 10, Green, RGBColor[
   0., 0.42, 0.04]],
  chessboard[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 10, Purple, Pink],
  chessboard[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 10, Blue, Cyan],
  },
 ImageSize -> 1000
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice use of `Tuples` in the first solution and `VertexTextureCoordinates` in the second solution.